# Getting resultset twice from statement

Tags: java, resultset

I understand that using `statement.getResultSet()` returns the result set as well as `statement.executeQuery()` but what happens if both are used like `executeQuery()` is called first and then `getResultSet()` is called after does it work or will it throw an exception that the result set has already been returned?

Comment: Best way to find out is to try it...

Comment: please update code

Comment: Why do you want to use this, or what is the occasion for asking this question?

Comment: I'm taking the ocpjp8 exam today and I just wanted to know if it does come out like this what I should pick as an answer

Comment: _getResultSet()_ returns the current _ResultSet_ object, that means if you didn't run a query before it will not be defined. So you have to run a query first, then you can use the method if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

Please look into this

executeQuery: Returns one ResultSet object.
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

Comment: I understand this thank you, but I was asking what if after this is done I call stmt.getResultSet() for another ResultSet, does the first result set close or does it return a new reference to the result set it holds. I know testing is the best way but I don't have any db to test with atm so your help will be very much appreciated thanks

Comment: whenever you run executeQuery it will return one new ResultSet object

Comment: while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");